# Meaning of "Bore many gentlemen" in Shakespeare's "Measure for Measure"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs, early-modern-english, shakespeare

In [act I, scene 5](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/MM_F1/scene/1.5/index.html), of *Measure for Measure*, Lucio says:

> **Lucio.** This is the point.
> The Duke is very strangely gone from hence;
> **Bore many gentlemen** (my selfe being one)
> In hand, and hope of action: but we doe learne,
> By those that know the very Nerues of State,
> His giuing-out, were of an infinite distance
> From his true meant designe: vpon his place,
> (And with full line of his authority)
> Gouernes Lord Angelo; [...]

I did some research on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bore#English) and [ShakespearesWords.com](https://www.shakespeareswords.com) but to no avail. What does "Bore many gentlemen" mean here?

Comment: Do you understand what **bear in hand** means?

Comment: Duke was accompanied by a group of gentlemen, and the speaker was among them.

Comment: @Sam: That doesn't really make sense, since the Duke ***is*** absent (gone from hence) - but the speaker is obviously still ***here***, so he can't have gone with the Duke. Unless Lucio has just returned from wherever the Duke took him (leaving the Duke still there), which seems contextually unlikely.

Comment: ...but I found [this...](http://shakespearestudyguide.com/MeasureText.html) *The duke is very strangely [secretly; mysteriously] gone from hence [here];    
Bore many gentlemen, myself being one,    
In hand and hope of action; but we do learn* -  He **left** many gentlemen, including me, wondering what would happen next; now we learn.

Comment: Answered on Literature SE -.https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/meaning-of-bore-many-gentlemen-in-shakespeares-measure-for-measure

Comment: FWIIW: in the following translation the meaning of “bore in hand” is translated as “he gave false hopes” (about taking military actions) - Lucio *È proprio questo il punto.

Il Duca è misteriosamente partito;

molti gentiluomini – me incluso – illuse

a sperare in azioni militari;*

Comment: @TimR I don't. What does that mean? Any reference?

Comment: John, I gave you a dictionary definition for **bear in hand** on the Literature forum yesterday!

Comment: To bear someone in hand is to "string them along", to mislead them about something  they are wishing for, over some (indefinite) period of time. These many gentlemen were being led by the duke to believe some action they desired was imminent.  There's also a play on words with the use of the preposition **in**: the duke ... bore many gentlemen.... *in hand* and (in)  hope of action.  The **in** of the idiom "bear in hand" is doing "double duty" so to speak by introducing the prepositional phrase "(in) hope of action".   Not quite sure how to characterize that sort of "wit".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the same user posted the same question in the Literature SE and it was answered there.